# Route53 transfer domains - nameserver options

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I'm trying to transfer hundreds of domain to AWS Route53. When I do it using AWS Route53 Console, during the transfer process I can set 'name-server option':
[image: Name-server options]

Does anyone know how I can approach the same thing using AWS CLI? I have already migrated my DNS records to Route53, so I'd like to use the 2nd option. I couldn't find anything in the documentation: [transfer-domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53domains/transfer-domain.html) . There is a 'nameservers' option, but there I can only define nameservers, but I want to use the Hosted Zone I've already created.

Here is my command:

> aws route53domains transfer-domain --region us-east-1 --domain-name
>   mydomain.co.uk --cli-input-json '{ ... }'

Comment: interesting, seems like it is just a convenience offered by web console, not something supported by api

Comment: I think I might have found the solution, I'm just testing it at the moment, will post it if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem, leave the answer here as it might be useful for someone else, too.

As I already [transferred the DNS Settings to Route53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html#domain-transfer-to-route-53-transfer-dns) I just have to gather the records:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $ZONEID --output json
```

Then scrape the nameservers from the output and place it in the transfer-domain command like this:

```
aws route53domains transfer-domain --region us-east-1 --domain-name $domain --cli-input-json '{
"DomainName": "'"$domain"'", 
"IdnLangCode": "", 
"DurationInYears": 1, 
"Nameservers": [
    {
        "Name": "nameserver1", 
        "GlueIps": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "nameserver2", 
        "GlueIps": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "nameserver3", 
        "GlueIps": []
    },
    {
        "Name": "nameserver4", 
        "GlueIps": []
    }
],

...}
```

This way Route53 will find the Hosted Zone with the same name as the domain and import the DNS records from it.